# PHP problema me duplica posts al actualizar uno con el metodo PUT en un endpoint

Tags: php, http, php7, endpoint

Tengo un problema que no consigo resolver.
Estoy desarrollando un plugin de wordpress y cuándo quiero actualizar posts que haya publicado, este se me modifica en la base de datos y me lo duplica, y no entiendo porque me duplica este post.

Estoy utilizando el método PUT para modificar los datos, os dejo por aquí el código con el que hago toda estas comprobaciones.

function updateAPost( $data ) {

```
    header("Content-Type: application/json;");          

    if ( isset( $data['id'] ) ) {

        $id = $data['id'];

    }   

    $post_data = array(
        'ID' => $id,
        'post_author' => $data['author'],
        'post_content' => $data['content'],
        'post_title' => $data['title'],
        'post_status' => $data['status'],
        'post_type' => $data['post']
    );

    if ( ! wp_is_post_revision( $data ) ){

        // unhook this function so it doesn't loop infinitely
        remove_action('edit_post', 'updateAPost');

        // update the post, which calls save_post again
        $id = wp_update_post( $post_data );

        // re-hook this function
        add_action('edit_post', 'updateAPost');
    }

    return ['Data' => $id, 'Status' => 'Modified'];

}
```

Si teneis alguna duda sobre esta funcion "wp_is_post_revision", lo que hace es resolver el problema del loop infinito al modificar los datos.

```
register_rest_route('authtoken', '/posts/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
        array( // Show a Post with ID [GET] /authtoken/posts/:id
            'methods' => 'GET',
            'callback' => 'getIdPost',
            'args' => array(
                'id' => array( 
                    'validate_callback' => function( $param, $request, $key ) {
                        return is_numeric( $param );
                    }
                ),
            )
        ),
        array( // Update a Post with ID [PUT] /authtoken/posts/:id
            'methods' => 'PUT',
            'callback' => 'updateAPost',
            'args' => array(
                'id' => array( 
                    'validate_callback' => function( $param, $request, $key ) {
                        return is_numeric( $param );
                    }
                ),
            )
        )
    ));
```

Esta route me recoge primero con el método GET el ID del post que quiero modificar, este me lo devuelve y seguidamente se lo paso a la función "updateAPost" para que me modifique los datos de ese post.

Alguién tiene solución a mi problema, un saludo.

Comment: Haz probado con `POST` en vez con `PUT` ?

Comment: Si, he probado con POST y me ocurre lo mismo.
He estado mirando y resulta ser problema de la función de wordpress "wp_update_post", pero no consigo encontrar información respecto a este problema.